# Reset Observable List

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

So I have an observable ArrayList that goes into a TableView in Java FX. Whenever I clear `weeksData.clear()`, I can't seem to reassign the variable. The table and the data just becomes empty. Does the `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` keep the original array that gets added and I am simply clearing the reference variable?

```
 ObservableList<Week> weeksData;
 weeksData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Login
[image]

Login first time
[image]

Login second time without clearing data
[image]

Login second time with `weeksData.clear();` even with following the clear with the same commands that populated the table the first time
[image]

I want to log back in to my program and not have the data reduplicate into my table. Just to rebuild it. Does this make more sense?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are asking. Could you describe a bit more what behavior you expected (with example), and what behavior you see right now?

Comment: @n247s I updated the description with pics to show you want I mean better. How else can I help?

Comment: What line of code are you using to add the test data to the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, I'm assuming you're populating your `TableView` with `tableView.getItems().addAll(weeksData);` or something similar, is that correct?  Essentially what that does is just copies all the elements of the `weeksData` list to the `tableView`'s list of items. When you clear or modify the underlying `weeksData` list, the `tableView` is not "notified," so to speak.

You should be setting the items in your `tableView` using the `setItems()` method:

```
ObservableList<Week> weeksData;
weeksData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tableView.setItems(weeksData);
```

This basically keeps your `weeksData` and `tableView` in sync.

The other option, if you don't want both lists to be in sync, is to call the `clear()` method on the `TableView`'s list of items instead:

```
tableview.getItems().clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It turns out the way I was populating the table was through a static and final object. When I cleared the weeksData, it filtered down and wipe the data from the connecting class field. Thanks for all the answers though!